# How to speak on microphone only when key is pressed

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use Skype and Brosic to make conference video calls with my friends. Often there is a noise from the background.

I use Centos and Ubuntu for workstation. Is there a way to configure Linux to activate the microphone only when I press a key for example `Shift`? I want people to hear me when I press `Shift` key.

Comment: I think this question would be better on Superuser. Voting to move.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this repo on bitbucket would suit your needs?

https://bitbucket.org/boralyl/skype-linux-push-to-talk

That one is only for Skype however. This one is for linux as a whole:

https://github.com/latestrevision/linux-push-to-talk

Comment: Yes, but this maybe will work only for Skype.

Comment: Yes, most likely since it's a skype addon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have personal experience with it, but over on the Skype forums, someone asked this and was referred to a sort of "Push to Mute", or "Push to toggle Mute" feature.  Kind of backwards I guess, but you can get a similar functionality out of it.  Quoting the [thread](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Where-is-push-to-talk-They-said-it-was-in-this-latest-build-Can/td-p/472055)...

> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Hotkeys. Select the last item and
>   assign a hotkey. Save.

I used a push to talk feature of Ventrillo regularly, and I must say, push to mute would probably not have been near as useful, but if you don't have the muscle memory of the opposite already burned in, this may suffice.  Plus it's apparently built-in to Skype.

Comment: The keybind actually pushes to reverse your current mute setting, oddly.  So, if you mute yourself using the UI element for the call, then the keybind acts as push-to-talk.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is quite easy to roll your own system using `xbindkeys`. For instance, to push-to-talk on the left super key, you have to put the following in your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"pacmd set-source-mute XXX 0 && notify-send 'Unmute' -t 50"
    Super_L


"pacmd set-source-mute XXX 1 && notify-send 'Mute' -t 50"
    Mod2+Mod4 + Super_L + Release
```

where `XXX` is the index of the source you want to mute. You can list all sources with `pacmd list-sources`. Make sure that `xbindkeys` is running.

Comment: Also, `xev -r (keycode)` to turn off auto-repeat will be useful if you want to map something which is not a modifier key (such as a spare F key).

Answer (score 0):

Metro style Skype doesn't reveal user setting for key binding and only have On/Off `Ctrl+M` key binding (switch, not push to talk):

- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-do-i-use-them-in-skype

Key binding customization is removed from today (2018-04-16) updated Desktop Skype:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_startms-skype_installms/how-do-i-set-my-hotkeys-on-skype-windows-10/23c66974-9fa6-4b39-86a1-ad49011c7fe4

Microsoft even pisses you if you are on Windows 10 and try to install Desktop Skype (Metro Skype doesn't have option to stay in background). It pushes you you to use Win 8 compatibility mode on installer. Otherwise it refuses to install Desktop version.